# How to convert scalaz-stream Process[F, Option[T]] to Process[F, T]?

Tags: scalaz-stream

I have a scalaz-stream process:

```
val src = Process.repeatEval(Task(in.take())) : Process[Task, Option[T]]
```

How do I get rid of Option?

So far I've used collect but it doesn't feel elegant:

```
src.collect { case Some(x) => x } : Process[Task, T]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, but the implementation is already present in scalaz-stream (<= 0.8), in `process1.stripNone`:

```
src.pipe(process1.stripNone)
```

or

```
src |> process1.stripNone
```

Many other transformations (possibly stateful) are defined in `process1`, so it's worth looking through the file for possibly useful transformations.